# como pesquisar mais de uma coluna no php

Tags: php, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou fazendo um pesquisador para um site de um cliente, fiz o código de formulário e o de pesquisa.e mostrou o resultado.

a minha tabela e assim:

NOME.DATA DE NASCIMENTO.IDADE.DATA DE FALECIMENTO.QUADRA.JAZIGO.GAVETA

no caso no momento o resultado e apenas do nome, mais preciso que seja das outras colunas também, quando eu colocar o nome da pessoa, aparece os outros dados da linha

código da pesquisa php:

```
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = " SENHA OCULTA";
    $database = "cemiterio";
    //Criar a conexao
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $database);

    $pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisar'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jazigos` WHERE `NOME` LIKE '%{$pesquisar}%' LIMIT 25";
    $resultado_cemiterio = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);

     while($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["NOME"]  ."<br>";


    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione as outras colunas no seu while também... você só especificou a coluna do nome, por isso somente a coluna nome está aparecendo:

```
  while($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["NOME"]  ."<br>";
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["DATA DE NASCIMENTO"]  ."<br>";
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["IDADE"]  ."<br>";
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["DATA DE FALECIMENTO"]  ."<br>";
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["QUADRA"]  ."<br>";
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["JAZIGO"]  ."<br>";
        echo "Resultado da Pesquisa:". $rows_sql["GAVETA"]  ."<br>";
        echo "------------------------------------------------<br>";

    }
```

Comment: ele deu erro:

Notice: Undefined index: DATA_DE_NASCIMENTO in C:\wamp64\www\Cemiterio\pesquisar.php on line 17

e esse tambem:

Notice: Undefined index: DATA_DE_FALECIMENTO in C:\wamp64\www\Cemiterio\pesquisar.php on line 19

Comment: Como é o nome das colunas no banco?

Comment: 1      ID
 2    NOME 
 3 DATA DE NASCIMENTO
 4 IDADE
 5 DATA DE FALECIMENTO
 6 QUADRA 
 7 JAZIGO
 8 GAVETA


mais a colona id nao precisa aparecer

Comment: DATA DE NASCIMENTO é com espaço mesmo?

Comment: a data de nascimento e da de falecimento e com espaço mesmo

Comment: Então onde estava DATA_DE_NASCIMENTO coloca DATA DE NASCIMENTO e DATA_DE_FALECIMENTO troca por DATA DE FALECIMENTO

Comment: estar dando certo, que alegria
qual comando para eu separar os resultados

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "separar os resultados?"

Comment: saiu assim o resultado:

Nome do Falecido:MARIA ODETE SOUSA
Data de Nascimento:20/1/1941*
Idade:
Data de Falecimento:26/12/2012+
Quadra:3
Jazigo:936
Gaveta:1
Nome do Falecido:MARIA ODETE SOUSA
Data de Nascimento:20/1/1941*
Idade:
Data de Falecimento:26/12/2012+
Quadra:3
Jazigo:936
Gaveta:1

Comment: ai queria formatar para separar tipo assim:

Nome do Falecido:MARIA ODETE SOUSA
Data de Nascimento:20/1/1941*
Idade:
Data de Falecimento:26/12/2012+
Quadra:3
Jazigo:936
Gaveta:1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Nome do Falecido:MARIA ODETE SOUSA
Data de Nascimento:20/1/1941*
Idade:
Data de Falecimento:26/12/2012+
Quadra:3
Jazigo:936
Gaveta:1

Comment: Editei a pergunta a acrescentei isso.. se estiver ok favor marcar a resposta como correta